# CSS animation tutorial

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I'm following a CSS basic animation tutorial but I've been stuck for a while and need some help to advance. The task is as follows:

I have two square figures, one blue and one red, together with four buttons (button 1, 2, 3 and 4), with button 1 the blue square will rotate right, with button 2 the blue square will rotate left.

With button 3 you start an animation of the red square to the left and then reversed back to its starting position. With the button 4 you pause the animation of the red square.

Now the problem is that I can't get any of these animations to work. And I can't find what's missing. My goal is to create an animation of blue square so that when you hit the rotate button the blue square will rotate 120degrees. But as it is for now it won't move, same with the red square.

I simpy don't know what to add/remove in order to make this blue square rotate and that is what I need help with.

Here is the JavaScript code for the buttons with an explanation of desired action.

Right button, when you hit button with the ID of 1 you first remove two classes "rotateright/rotateleft" so it's starting position is zero. Then we add the class of "rotateright" again to rotate the blue square 120degrees. :

```js
document.getElementById('button1').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('blue').classList.remove('rotateright', 'rotateleft');
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('blue').classList.add('rotateright');
  }, 100)
});

document.getElementById('button2').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('blue').classList.remove('rotateleft');
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('blue').classList.add('rotateleft');
  }, 100)
});

document.getElementById('button3').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('red').classList.add('animate');
});

document.getElementById('button4').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('red').classList.remove('animate');
});
```

```css
#background {
  background-color: #f3f3ff;
  width: 240px;
  height: 100px;
  border: medium;
}
#blue {
  background-color: #aaaaff;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  border: thin;
  border-color: #000;
  border-width: 1px;
}
#red {
  background-color: #ffaaaa;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 150px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: thin;
  border-color: #000;
  border-width: 1px;
}
.animate {
  -webkit-animation-name: example;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: example;
}
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */

@-webkit-keyframes example {
  0% {
    right: 750px;
    top: 8px;
  }
  25% {
    right: 800px;
    top: 8px;
  }
  50% {
    right: 850px;
    top: 8px;
  }
  75% {
    right: 800px;
    top: 8px;
  }
  100% {
    right: 750;
    top: 8px;
  }
}
/* Standard syntax */

@keyframes example {
  0% {
    right: 750px;
    top: 8px;
  }
  25% {
    right: 800px;
    top: 8px;
  }
  50% {
    right: 850px;
    top: 8px;
  }
  75% {
    right: 800px;
    top: 8px;
  }
  100% {
    right: 750;
    top: 8px;
  }
}
#button1 {
  width: 40px;
}
#button2 {
  width: 40px;
}
#button3 {
  width: 40px;
}
#button4 {
  width: 40px;
}
.rotateright {
  -webkit-animation-name: rotateright1;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-name: rotateright1;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */

@-webkit-keyframes rotateright1 {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(60deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(120deg);
  }
}
/* Standard syntax */

@keyframes rotateright1 {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(60deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(120deg);
  }
}
.rotateleft {
  -webkit-animation-name: rotateleft1;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-name: rotateleft1;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */

@-webkit-keyframes rotateleft1 {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(-0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(-60deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-120deg);
  }
}
/* Standard syntax */

@keyframes rotateleft1 {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(-0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(-60deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-120deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="background">
  <div id="blue"></div>
  <div id="red"></div>
</div>
<button id="button1">right</button>
<button id="button2">left</button>
<button id="button3">play red</button>
<button id="button4">stop red</button>
<br>
<a href="CSSanimation.html">CSS animation</a>
<a href="index.html">Index</a>
<a href="raphaelJS.html">Raphael JS</a>
<a href="burst2.html">Burst</a>
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**

Comment: "While in JSfiddle, the red one moves but out of control, but when I run the same code in "preview localhost" neither the blue or the red one moves an inch." — That sounds like two completely different problems. Try focusing on one problem at a time.

Comment: @Quentin Alright, let's start with the blue. As you can see in fiddle whenever you hit button #1 or #2 the blue square rotates 120degrees. I have tried to updated the code with some name changes and such but without success.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**

Comment: Try editing your question so it is (a) complete and (b) not too broad.

Comment: @Quentin I thought I were clear enough but I edited the question. Did you click the fiddle link to get an overview of the code. It's quite a small project.

Comment: On a different website at the other end of a link is not "in the question itself" even if it is small. Stackoverflow supports [live demos](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) without having to link off to third parties.

Comment: @Quentin Oh, did not know about this new feature. Well, I used the new code snippet end added it to my question.